# How to import .pl file on SWI PROLOG?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I just downloaded the SWI PROLOG for mac, and for some reason there's no 'import' button in the menu bar. So, I was wondering if there's any way I could import the .pl file using code maybe, and how I can include the path of the .pl file in my code.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Consult` command under the `File` menu.

From the query prompt (`?-`), you can put the path to the file as a string inside of square brackets:

```
?- ['~/Desktop/my_pgm.pl'].
```

Comment: I don't have it in my version, that's why I'm asking; if there's any other way. But, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a ?- prompt.

type the name of your file in square brackets, like Scott says

Answer (score 0):

maybe you renamed the executable in some way ? On Linux, I'm experiencing a similar issue (no menubar at all) if I copy a link from the build folder to desktop, where then it's seen as `Link to swipl-win`. Renaming the link to `swipl-win` adjust the menubar as well. So strange...

Comment: How does this answer the question about consulting a file?

Comment: without menubar, it's difficult to actionate the menu :)

Comment: @ScottHunter: I'm (kind of) in charge of the swipl-win Qt port, practically required for MacOS, so I attempt to help on UX problems...

Comment: Not sure how not answering someone's question helps w/ UX.